# "Make sure your Magento cron job is running." after installation

Tags: magento2

I am trying to run Magento 2.2 on my local machine. It has been installed successfully but in the backend, I am seeing this error.

> Make sure your Magento cron job is running

How can I correct this? I am using `Linux ubuntu`.

Answer (score 1):

Just follow these steps:

- Open the terminal and enter below command:

> cd [document_root_of_magento]

then run below command:

> php bin/magento indexer:reindex

Please check and let me know if you find any problem.